# Recycler Item view not properly displaying data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I press back button this ShoppingActivity gets destroy and when I visit that activity again I finds my recycler view items replaced twice. How do I resolve that problem?

ShoppingActivity.java
 All the code written here and volley class also being called here when I press back and visit that activity again I find my recycler view items gets replaced
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping);

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    btn_sort_name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_name);
    btn_sort_price = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_price);

    tv_total_products = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalproduct);
    tv_apihits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apihits);

    tv_total_products.setText(null);

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
    final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            BaseUrl,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    int index = 0;
                    arrayList.clear();
                    while (index < response.length()) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(index);
                            arrayList.add(new Items(jsonObject.getString("name"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("description"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("category"),
                                    jsonObject.getDouble("price"),
                                    jsonObject.getInt("quantity"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("shipping"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("location"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("color"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("link")));
                            da = jsonObject.getString("name");
                            Log.d(TAG, da);
                            index++;
                            total_products = index;
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(arrayList, ShoppingActivity.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                    tv_total_products.append(String.valueOf(total_products));

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error");
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewItemClick(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView,
            new RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void clickedItem(View view, int position) {

                    name = arrayList.get(position).getName();
                    description = arrayList.get(position).getDescription();
                    category = arrayList.get(position).getCategory();
                    shipping = arrayList.get(position).getShipping();
                    location = arrayList.get(position).getLocation();
                    color = arrayList.get(position).getColor();
                    link = arrayList.get(position).getLink();
                    price = arrayList.get(position).getPrice();
                    quantity = arrayList.get(position).getQuantity();
                    DataParcel dataParcel = new DataParcel(name, description, category, shipping, location, color, link, price, quantity);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingActivity.this, DetailsViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("data", dataParcel);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }));

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

And this is my DetailsViewActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_view);

    btn_back= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    btn_link= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_link);
    btn_share= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    btn_sms= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sms);
    tv_description= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_description);

    tv_app_name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_app_name);

    category= (Button) findViewById(R.id.category);
    price= (Button) findViewById(R.id.price);
    location= (Button) findViewById(R.id.location);
    quantity= (Button) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    shipping= (Button) findViewById(R.id.shipping);

    iv_star1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.star1);
    iv_star2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.star2);
    iv_star3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.star3);
    iv_star4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.star4);
    iv_item_image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_image);

    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    dataParcel= bundle.getParcelable("data");
    category.setText(dataParcel.getCategory());
    price.setText(String .valueOf(dataParcel.getPrice()));
    quantity.setText("Avilable"+String.valueOf(    dataParcel.getQuantity() ));
    location.setText(dataParcel.getLocation());
    shipping.setText("Shipping: "+dataParcel.getShipping());
    tv_app_name.setText(dataParcel.getName());
    tv_description.setText(dataParcel.getDescription());


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Could you set `LayoutManager` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with lifecycle of your activity, you can check if the instance of first activity is still there while returning from another activity.
For quick fix you can clear your arraylist before populating it with data, this will clear previously added data when returning from another activity, you can do it as

```
arrayList.clear();
```

before

```
 while(index<response.length())
```

on the response block. But this is just a quick fix not the actual solution, so better idea will be checking the instance of the class.